# Custom nginx configuration variables not being expanded

Tags: nginx

I am running nginx version 1.2.8.

It seems that `$log` and `$elog` in the below configuration are not expanded, and as a result, nothing is logged.  Is that the problem, and how can I get them to expand?

nginx Config:

```
server {
    listen              xx.xx.xx.xx:80 default;
    server_name         domain.com;
    set                 $docroot                /home/domain.com/public_html;
    set                 $log                    /home/domain.com/logs/access_log;
    set                 $elog                   /home/domain.com/logs/error_log;
    root                $docroot;
    error_log           $elog;
    include             /etc/nginx/http-backend.conf;

}
```

/etc/nginx/http-backend.conf config:

```
.....
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|ico|swf|txt|tgz|tbz|pdfpls|torrent)$ {
    root                $docroot;
    try_files           $uri @fallback;
    access_log          $log            main;
    error_log           $elog;
    expires             30d;
    add_header          Pragma          "public";
    add_header          Cache-Control   "public";
#    error_page         404 = @fallback;
}
.....
```

UPD: Thanks to [Valery Viktorovsky](https://serverfault.com/users/3791) i resolved this by changing permissions to logs folders.

```
chown -R apache.root /home/*/logs/
chmod -R 750 /home/*/logs/
```

Mentioned workaround, slightly  modified, has been applied also. It doesn't work without it, even with right permissions. Values of `$log` and `$elog` remains unchanged, but the slash is added.

Updated /etc/nginx/http-backend.conf config:

```
.....
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|ico|swf|txt|tgz|tbz|pdfpls|torrent)$ {
    root                $docroot;
    try_files           $uri @fallback;
#    access_log          $log            main;
#    error_log           $elog;
    access_log          /$log            main;
    error_log           /$elog;
    expires             30d;
    add_header          Pragma          "public";
    add_header          Cache-Control   "public";
#    error_page         404 = @fallback;
}
.....
```

There is still a problem, because apache creates log files with owner root.
To partially solve this, same commands have been added to logrotate config:

```
/home/*/logs/*_log {
    missingok
    notifempty
    weekly
    minsize 50M
    compress
    rotate 60
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /sbin/service nginx reload > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
        /sbin/service httpd reload > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
        chown -R apache.root /home/*/logs/ > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
        chmod -R 750 /home/*/logs/ > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nginx workers must have rights to create files in /home/domain.com/logs

So check permissions for /home/domain.com/logs directory.

Also you can use small workaround:

```
server {
    set        $log                    'home/domain.com/logs/access_log';
    access_log  /$log;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to right direction.
I misunderstood that part regarding permissions on log folder.